# SQL Server : build CSV from two tables

Tags: sql-server, database, dynamic

Consider the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_person
(
     pid int,               -- Person ID
     lname varchar(255),    -- Last Name
     fname varchar(255) -- First Name
);

INSERT INTO #temp_person (pid, lname, fname) 
VALUES (1, 'Smith', 'Bob'),
       (2, 'Jones', 'Sally'),
       (3, 'Edwards', 'Frank');

CREATE TABLE #temp_fruit_person
(
    fid int,            -- Fruit ID
    name varchar(255),  -- Fruit Name
    pid int             -- Person ID
)

INSERT INTO #temp_fruit_person (fid, name, pid) 
VALUES (555, 'Orange', 1), (555, 'Orange', 2),
       (666, 'Apple', 1), (666, 'Apple', 3),
       (777, 'Banana', 1), (777, 'Banana', 3);
```

I need to export this data in an API as a CSV in a specific format for an automated upload.  They want the amount of "columns" in the CSV to be dynamic based on the amount of fruit associated with each person.  So, the CSV would contain enough columns to make sure that all of the fruit was covered.  An example of the results required:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pid | lname | fname | fruit_name_1 | fruit_id_1 | fruit_name_2 | fruit_id_2 | fruit_name_3 | fruit_id_3 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1  | Smith |  Bob  |    Orange    |    555     |     Apple    |    666     |    Banana    |    777     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2  | Jones | Sally |    Orange    |    555     |     NULL     |    NULL    |     NULL     |    NULL    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3  | Clark | Eddy  |    Apple     |    666     |    Banana    |    777     |     NULL     |    NULL    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The idea is that the column names are dynamic... and in the real data will likely go into the 40s.  I hate the way they're requesting this data and would prefer to give them two separate exports, but I've got to work within the requirements.

I have tried using `STUFF` in combination with `FOR XML PATH`, but the source data includes things that might already have commas in them.  So, I really need the multiple fruit results to actually be separate columns.

Comment: One option is you can do `quotename(Column, '"')` first so that you're quoting your fields. Then the commas won't be treated as field delimiters, but string literals

Comment: The issue is that when I use STUFF with FOR XML PATH, it comes back as:

1,"Smith","Bob","Orange","555,Apple,666,Banana"

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to serialize it?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,p.pid) + ',' +
    char(34) + p.lname + char(34) + ',' +
    char(34) + p.fname + char(34) + ',' +
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar,fid) + ',' + char(34) + name + char(34) FROM #temp_fruit_person WHERE pid = p.pid
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as fruit_list
FROM #temp_person p

UNION

SELECT 'pid,lname,fname,fid01,fidname01,fid02,fidname02,fid03,fidname03'

ORDER BY fruit_list DESC
```

When I output it in text mode and tell it to output in CSV without column headers (and outputting status messages in another tab), I get:

```
pid,lname,fname,fid01,fidname01,fid02,fidname02,fid03,fidname03
3,"Clark","Frank",666,"Apple",777,"Banana"
2,"Jones","Sally",555,"Orange"
1,"Smith","Bob",555,"Orange",666,"Apple",777,"Banana"
```